Import a jar file with maven dependency in jmeter
My end goal is I need to fetch a data from API response and write that to an excel. And tools I am using in jmeter.
My Approach is the following:
file 1: I have a java file using Apache POI for writing in excel. I have created the fat jar of the java file.
file 2: Create one simple java file (without any pom/maven). Import the jar created in file 1. Set the jar from project Libraries and run it.
However, I am getting the following error with that approach:
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.xerces.parsers.ObjectFactory$ConfigurationError: Provider org.apache.xerces.parsers.XIncludeAwareParserConfiguration not found

I have downloaded the xerces jar after getting this error and getting another error now.
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.poi.ooxml.POIXMLException: org.apache.poi.openxml4j.exceptions.InvalidFormatException: Can't read content types part !

I am not able to find any solution for this. Suggest me if there is any alternate solution for reaching into my end goal.
I am trying this using the java jar file import in jmeter.
Expectation:

Can I write the code directly in jmeter by solving the maven dependency in jmeter ?
How can I run the maven dependency jar file from a normal java file ?

My Code for file1:

package org.excel;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFRow;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

public class TestWriteInExcel {
    public TestWriteInExcel() {
    }

    public static void writeXLSXFile(int row, int col, String actualValue, String fname) throws IOException {
        Cell cell = null;

        try {
            FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(fname);
            XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(file);
            XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
            XSSFRow sheetrow = sheet.getRow(row);
            if (sheetrow == null) {
                sheetrow = sheet.createRow(row);
            }

            cell = sheetrow.getCell(col);
            if (cell == null) {
                cell = sheetrow.createCell(col);
            }

            cell.setCellValue(actualValue);
            file.close();
            FileOutputStream outFile = new FileOutputStream(fname);
            workbook.write(outFile);
            outFile.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException var10) {
            FileNotFoundException e = var10;
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException var11) {
            IOException e = var11;
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}

my pom file for this:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>testWriteinExcel</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <!-- Maven Shade Plugin -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.4</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <minimizeJar>true</minimizeJar>
                            <filters>
                                <filter>
                                    <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                                    <excludes>
                                        <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                                        <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                                        <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
                                    </excludes>
                                </filter>
                            </filters>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.syncthemall</groupId>
            <artifactId>boilerpipe</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- JMeter Core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.jmeter</groupId>
            <artifactId>ApacheJMeter_core</artifactId>
            <version>5.5</version> <!-- Choose the JMeter version you're working with -->
        </dependency>

        <!-- JMeter HTTP Samplers -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.jmeter</groupId>
            <artifactId>ApacheJMeter_http</artifactId>
            <version>5.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- JMeter Java Sampler -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.jmeter</groupId>
            <artifactId>ApacheJMeter_java</artifactId>
            <version>5.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- JMeter Dependencies (Optional) -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.jmeter</groupId>
            <artifactId>ApacheJMeter_junit</artifactId>
            <version>5.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.30</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>

My Code for file2 where I am calling the file1:
package example1.test;

import org.excel.TestWriteInExcel;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        int row = 1;
        int col = 0;
        String actualValue =  "IFT Instant Single";
        TestWriteInExcel.writeXLSXFile(row,col,actualValue,"E:/Practice/Test_for_excel/filename.xlsx");

        col = col+1;
        String tf = "7778899I" ;
        TestWriteInExcel.writeXLSXFile(row,col,tf,"E:/Practice/Test_for_excel/filename.xlsx");

    }
}


The Can't read content types part error means that your file is either broken or it's in Excel binary format (xls) and not xlsx
Try running this code without JMeter (in plain Java) and see whether the issue is still present. If it's JMeter-specific only - enable JMeter debug logging and check jmeter.log file for any suspicious entries, it might be some form of a Jar Hell
More information: Busy Developers' Guide to HSSF and XSSF Features

It is not jmeter specific. I tried to import the jar in a plain java file and got the 'Can't read content types part' error
